# avoid rendering a simple_form component based on the attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have a `CustomInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base` that I would like to avoid rendering if the attribute value is blank.  IOW, I want to avoid rendering all the wrappers and components. Can I do this within the control to avoid writing `if model.attribute.blank?` for each control in my template?

Comment: I posted this in the simple_form google group as well https://groups.google.com/d/topic/plataformatec-simpleform/D-_u2LHmTHw/discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass the `FormBuilder` and override the `input` method

```
class MyFormBuilder < SimpleForm::FormBuilder

  def input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block)
    if @template.my_action_show?
      return if @object.send(attribute_name).blank?
    end 
    super
  end
```

`my_action_show?` is just custom `ApplicationHelper` method that checks if

```
params[:action]=='show'
```